# Streaming filter sample code usage issue

Tags: java, twitter4j

```
import twitter4j.FilterQuery;
import twitter4j.StallWarning;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.StatusDeletionNotice;
import twitter4j.StatusListener;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.TwitterStream;
import twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class winning {

    public static ConfigurationBuilder cb;
    public static TwitterFactory tf;
    public static twitter4j.Twitter tw;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {   

        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("-")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("");        

         tf= new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
         tw= tf.getInstance();       


        if (args.length > 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java twitter4j.examples.PrintFilterStream [follow(comma separated numerical user ids)] [track(comma separated filter terms)]");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
                System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
                System.out.println("Got track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
                System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {
                System.out.println("Got stall warning:" + warning);
            }

            @Override
            public void onException(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        ArrayList<Long> follow = new ArrayList<Long>();
        ArrayList<String> track = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String arg : args) {
            if (isNumericalArgument(arg)) {
                for (String id : arg.split(",")) {
                    follow.add(Long.parseLong(id));
                }
            } else {
                track.addAll(Arrays.asList(arg.split(",")));
            }
        }
        long[] followArray = new long[follow.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < follow.size(); i++) {
            followArray[i] = follow.get(i);
        }
        String[] trackArray = track.toArray(new String[track.size()]);

        // filter() method internally creates a thread which manipulates TwitterStream and calls these adequate listener methods continuously.
        twitterStream.filter(new FilterQuery(0, followArray, trackArray));
    }

    private static boolean isNumericalArgument(String argument) {
        String args[] = argument.split(",");
        boolean isNumericalArgument = true;
        for (String arg : args) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(arg);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                isNumericalArgument = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isNumericalArgument;
    }   
}
```

this is a sample code from twitter4j.

Everytime i try to run this i keep getting

"Usage: java twitter4j.examples.PrintFilterStream [follow(comma separated numerical user ids)] [track(comma separated filter terms)]"

even tho i added track array.and separated with , so it can get split-ed and add it to list indexes.

or have i miss understood the usage?

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

you `winning` class ( Please following naming conventions and start Class names with a Capital letter), accepts command line arguments as  an array of *Strings*  `String[] args`

```
if (args.length > 1) {
```

You have this above code, which condition is obviously becoming true, since you mentioned that you see the sysout *"Usage: java twitter4j.examples.PrintFilterStream [follow(comma separated numerical user ids)] [track(comma separated filter terms)]"* in output and program exits.

So, you have to ensure that you pass only ***one*** argument as input to your program, so args.length remains only **1**

looking at your code you later use the *args* to split it with **,**.
So your input to the program must look something like

> "1,2,3,4,5,6"
>
> "a,b,c,d,e,f"

Your program invocation from command line should look something like:

```
java winning "1,2,3,4,5,6"
```

For your reference and learning
[Command line arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)
[Command args](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/09/command-args.html)